# the javascript code stop working while ajax load

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

- The code 1: When I click on the "click here" it's supposed to hide the `div` with "id=adiv", and when I click again its show it again.
- The code 2 and 3: the ajax code (code 2) belongs to code 3. this codes just refresh php page every 1 second. i put the code 1 in php page that i open with ajax!

Why after the ajax code (code 2&3) loads in the page, the 'code 1' stops working? When I click on "click here", its doing nothing.

But before the ajax load, the code 1 works good.

the codes 2 and 3 works good, i have no problem with them. the only problem is with code 1.

when i debug this page its show me for the line: "hideshow(document.getElementById('adiv'))" (in code 1), this eror: "Uncaught ReferenceError: hideshow is not defined (anonymous function)".

but i dont really understand why i have this problem? and what i need to do to solve this?

*edit:* **someone here said that becouse the code 1 is in page that i open with ajax, the code is erased from the client's dom. there is solution for this?**

1) The script:

```
<a href="javascript:hideshow(document.getElementById('adiv'))">Click here</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
function hideshow(which){
if (!document.getElementById) { return; }
if (which.style.display=="block") { which.style.display="none"; }
else { which.style.display="block"; }
}
</script>

<div id="adiv" style="font:24px bold; display: block">Now you see me</div>
```

2) The ajax code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function refresh(name, url, info, info_1, info_2, type)
{
    if (type == "send") {
        document.getElementById("send_"+name).innerHTML = info;  // just show the txt that send
        Input(name);
        if (info == "") {
            document.getElementById(name).innerHTML="";
            return;
        } 
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {  // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var params = "c=<?php echo $_GET["c"]; ?>&info="+info+"&info_1="+info_1+"&info_2="+info_2;
    xhr.open("POST",url,true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if( this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById(name).innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    };
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
    xhr.send(params);
    return false;
}
</script>
```

3) The code that play the ajax code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
           setInterval("refresh('aaa', 'refresh.php', '', '', '', 'refresh')", "1000");
           </script>
```

Comment: is your javascript inside a div or other element that the ajax code overwrites? if so, that code is erased from the client's dom.

Comment: @developerwjk yes, the code 1 is inside page that i open with ajax. there is solution for this?